# Parse Facebook API - Callback for real-time updates using facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, webhooks

I am using Parse's cloud backend. I am logging my users in using the ParseFacebook utils but would also like to subscribe to changes in their profile using the following :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0#setup

However, this requires a callback url to communicate with and unfortunately, i was unable to find anything in the parse documents. Will i need to set up a custom webhook on parse or is there something that i missed out? Also if i need to set up a webhook to handle get and post, could someone post a link to an easy intro to webhooks, since i do not know anything abiut them.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use ngrok app to test webhook parsing in local environment. Look at following url:
https://ngrok.com/

It converts your "http:/localhost/folder/" into "http://asdhjsd.ngrok.io/folder/"
i.e usable to test webhooks or other integration.