# Integrating Facebook Real time API with Parse.com

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm working on a project where If a certain Facebook page (page id known) posts a new post, It gets copied to my Parse App Class.

Now I know that it can be done using facebook real time api (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3) where once if subscribed for a certain update, facebook will make a HTTP POST request to a certain url.

How do I get this url? Do I need to have a server where I handle the post request? If so how?
Also Can be it achieved using parse cloud code only ?

Thanks

Comment: You don’t “get” that URL, you have to _provide_ it. It is your part to set such a system up, and get it to accept the JSON POSTs from Facebook. For parse, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429538/parse-facebook-api-callback-for-real-time-updates-using-facebook-api suggests that you can do it by setting up a custom webhook. https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#webhooks

Comment: @iitum studant have you found any code snippet for above ?

Comment: @βhargavḯ : Hi, I found the solution. Please refer to the accepted answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208967/receiving-real-time-page-feed-update-using-facebooks-real-time-update-api