# Receiving real-time Page feed update using facebook's real time update api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I want to receive a real time notification update whenever there is a new post on a particular page. I've referred to facebook's real-time update api guide for this (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3)

I've subscribed to page feed update for my app:

[image]

My app has "manage_pages" permission:

```
<fb:login-button scope="manage_pages" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
```

After the admin of the page logs in with my app I should be receiving pafe feed updates right? But it does not work.

Some people mentioned that I have to make a post request to this url (https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/tabs?app_id=APPID&method=POST&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN) so that I get update from that particular page.

I tried this too which gave a response true but I'm still not receiving any updates when the page makes new posts.

If anyone has achieved this, please post a detailed How-To. I'd really appreciate it. Facebook's documentation are not good.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the new [subscribed_apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/subscribed_apps) endpoint - no need to add the App to a Page for that one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/subscribed_apps

In order to make Realtime Updates work, you need to use [subscribed_apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/subscribed_apps) and the [subscriptions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/app/subscriptions) endpoint.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Worked like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: @luschn Sorry to hi-jack, but I think I have the exact issue. I did a ```GET``` to ```v2.3/{page_id}/subscribed_apps/``` and I can see the App name and id listed in the ```data``` array, but I'm still not getting realtime updates coming through. Is there a checklist ? Feels like I'm missing something, but not sure what

Comment: subscribed_apps is not enough, you need to add a subscription too. read the last part of my answer, there is a link.

Comment: @luschn I think I added the subscription beforehand and when I do a ```GET``` I can see it's registered: ```{
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "user", 
      "callback_url": "URL_HERE", 
      "fields": [
        "statuses"
      ], 
      "active": true
    }, 
    {
      "object": "page", 
      "callback_url": "URL_HERE", 
      "fields": [
        "feed"
      ], 
      "active": true
    }
  ]
}```. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: @luschn Does the app need to be approved for Realtime Updates to work ?

Comment: @luschn Thank you, that's great news. I've re-read the docs and spotted this: " (Note: some of these objects may require your app to be whitelisted by Facebook for access.)". Thought that's why the callbacks aren't coming through. I'm really getting frustrated with their API. It should be simple, I think I did what they asked, but I'm not sure what else is missing. I may post a separate question here on SO although it will be very similar to this one

Comment: the api is very simple imho, only the realtime api isn´t :)

Comment: @luschn and that's precisely the one I need to use :'( I've posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921972/how-to-easily-use-the-facebook-api-realtime-updates-feature