# How to easily use the Facebook API Realtime Updates feature?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First off, apologies for posting yet another question on Facebook Realtime Updates. I have read many existing stackoverflow answers and useful articles which helped, but I still can't seem to figure out how to put everything together.

All I'm trying to do is get a trigger when there's a user or page updates (be it status/comment/like/etc.) in realtime.

I started with the [Realtime Updates documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3) and found these two blog posts handy:

- [Facebook Realtime Updates](http://ilkkah.com/2015/02/23/facebook-real-time-updates/)
- [FaceBook Real-Time Updates API Tutorial - Part I](http://www.codedestination.com/blog/-facebook-real-time-updates-api-tutorial-part-i)

From what I understood, to register for Realtime Updates, I need to:

1. Create a WWW Facebook app
2. Point the Facebook app to a `callback_url`
3. Add a php script at the `callback_url` to handle a GET request (for verification) and POST requests when Facebook calls.
4. Register the callback with the Graph API (`v2.3/APP_ID/subscriptions`)
5. Add the Facebook Login button to the page (including the scope/permissions needed) and perform the login action

In theory, after this point, Facebook should POST to the `callback_url` based on the registered object and fields.

I think I've successfully registered the callback. Here roughly the output I get(with `MY_CB_URL` replacing the actual URL):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "user", 
      "callback_url": "MY_CB_URL", 
      "fields": [
        "statuses"
      ], 
      "active": true
    }, 
    {
      "object": "page", 
      "callback_url": "MY_CB_URL", 
      "fields": [
        "feed"
      ], 
      "active": true
    }
  ]
}
```

The callback php script looks like so:

```
<?php

define('VERIFY_TOKEN', 'vToken');

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' && $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == VERIFY_TOKEN) {

    echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];

} else if ($method == 'POST') {

    $out = "";

    try {

        $updates = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

        $out = print_r($updates, true);

        error_log('updates = ' . $out);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log('Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage());
        $out = $e->getMessage();
    }

    $file = './log.txt';
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    $current .= $out;
    file_put_contents($file, $current);

}

?>
```

The problem I have is I got a single POST request when I first set this up, but none after that. I don't get any errors and the API confirms the callback is correctly registered, so I am clueless on what I may be missing.

I've spotted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208967/receiving-real-time-page-feed-update-using-facebooks-real-time-update-api) and make a call as suggested to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs?app_id=APP_ID&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

and got this response:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "PAGE_ID/tabs/likes",
         "name": "Likes",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE_NAME/PAGE_ID?sk=likes",
         "is_permanent": true,
         "position": 2,
         "is_non_connection_landing_tab": false
      },
      {
         "id": "PAGE_ID/tabs/photos",
         "image_url": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t39.2080-0/851586_10151609549247733_1069686154_n.gif",
         "name": "Photos",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE_NAME/PAGE_ID?sk=photos",
         "application": {
            "name": "Photos",
            "id": "PHOTO_ID"
         },
         "is_permanent": false,
         "position": 1,
         "is_non_connection_landing_tab": false
      }
   ]
}
```

So now I'm further confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs` is *outdated* – you need to use `/PAGE_ID/subscribed_apps` now to subscribe to updates from a page.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/

Comment: I can see that app is linked, at least according to the Graph API:``` {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "APP_NAME", 
      "id": "APP_ID"
    }
  ]
}``` but I'm still not getting any updates. I've tried posting on both my account and the facebook page, but no joy so far

Comment: My bad, found the issue: the url as the path to the folder because my script is called index.php. The path should be explicit (including the path to the .php, not just the folder)